# Azure Key Vault certificate - create Basic Constraints CA:True

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I would like to create a self signed CA certificate via Azure portal (Azure Key Vault). I am not sure how to set X509 extension  Basic Constraints CA:True

Some reference link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps

https://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.5.29.19.html

(Note: I need to do it manually via Azure Portal, not the openssl or PowerShell script)

How I tried to do

[image]

And what I get
[image]

My expectation is CA:True. Thank you for your helps :)

Answer (score 6):

Apparently this works though the REST API, but is unfortunately neither exposed through the Portal UI nor through the .NET Client SDK. Also, it's not properly documented right now.

When you look at the [example response for the Get Certificate Policy endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getcertificatepolicy/getcertificatepolicy#getcertificatepolicy), you can see that it has a section `"basic_constraints"` with the value you're looking for (even though it's not documented in the respective [X509CertificateProperties section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getcertificatepolicy/getcertificatepolicy#x509certificateproperties) further down on the same page).

The property is however documented in the general ["D509 props" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/certificates-and-policies#d509-props) for the REST API. Mind the typo in `path_len_contraint` though if you want to use that -- needs to be `path_len_constraint`.

So when POSTing to `https://<yourvault>.vault.azure.net/certificates/some-new-cert/create?api-version=7.0` using

```
    "x509_props": {
        ...
        "key_usage": [
            "keyCertSign"
        ],
        "basic_constraints": {
            "ca": true,
            "path_len_constraint": 3
        }
    },
```

it actually sets the values as expected. See [Create Certificate documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/createcertificate/createcertificate#createcertificate) for other parameters.

The result can be seen in the openssl dump of the exported certificate:

```
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Certificate Sign
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE, pathlen:3
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to be possible to do this anymore.

Comment: Can't try it out right now. Would find it strange that they disable that functionality now though, especially since they acknowledged this use case and started working on fixing the documentation just a few days ago: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/8295#issuecomment-692242023
BTW, estiller confirmed that it still worked end of May: https://github.com/estiller/build-pki-net-azure-sample/issues/1#issuecomment-634914394

Comment: I can confirm this still works via REST but not via the SDKs.